# Clairaut ODE and first order high degree ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Are Clairaut ODE and First order High degree ODE related ?? If yes , what is the relationship ?

In addition , I want the name of a reference that contains a good explanation for them .

Comment: see here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SHQ1FMyqIo

Answer (score 0):

Not every first order high degree ODE is a Clairaut DE. These are only of the form $y=xy'+f(y')$ and derived equations obtained by variable changes. The perfect factorization of the derivative of the DE
$$
y'=y'+xy''+f'(y')y''\implies 0=y''\,(x+f'(y')) 
$$
into a term containing the second derivative and another only containing the first order derivative (and the variables) is characteristic for all these variants. It is easy to see that most variations in coefficients or by additional terms will destroy this factorization.